# Position a view relative to its top left corner instead of center

Tags: swift, swiftui

I just ran into the problem, that I wanted to get a Text positioned inside my view using its top left corner. This is because I use an SVG-file as input, where the positions are given that way. In SwiftUI the `.position(x: 10.0, y: 10.0)` does position the center of a view. So the result was that my Text had an offset I could not remove generically as I do not know the length of the text before I get it. And writing code, that would be able to use text length, font and size (and perhaps more) to calculate an offset is really not a solution I am willing to work on.

So this is not possible, since the text centers around (0,0) and is half outside the view:

```
Text("I am a dummy")
    .position(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
```

[image]

And the solution to use basic spacers does not work when I want the text at other random positions than 0 and 0.

```
Text("I am a dummy")
Spacer()
```

I have not found another Post here, where a solution to that specific problem is given.

Comment: For me `.position(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)` works... can you show an image of the result that you want?

Comment: Added an image of what it does with (0,0). The text is half outside the view, but I want its top left corner start at (0,0). Until now it only worked with the option in the answer.

Comment: Well, if I want this to work for all x and y that is, if I would want the (0,0) as top left corner I could also just take to normal spacers. Thing is : my answer works fine with all positions i set, but it is certainly not a beautiful solution.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up with is a quite big workaraound that should work for all x and y positions defined from the top left corner:

```
VStack {
    Spacer(minLength: pos.x)
    HStack {
        Spacer(minLength: pos.x)
        Text("I am a dummy")
        Spacer()
            .frame(idealWidth: 10000)
    }
    Spacer()
        .frame(idealHeight: 10000)
}
```

So what I do, is that I set my Text inside a `VStack` and a `HStack` and for each stack I set a `Spacer()` on both sides of the text. This would place it in the middle. So to fix this I set the minimum length for the spacers that are on top and on the left side, each the value our position should be (here `pos.x` and `pos.y`). Now we just have to make sure the other spacers take all the space they can get so that the ones with minimum lengthes really only get that minimum length. To do that we give the other spacers a `frame` with a ridiculous `idealWidth` or `idealHeight`, depending on which it is. And now the top left corner of my text is positioned at the position defined by `pos`.

I tested this only on an iPad Pro, but it should work for iOS and macOS, as SwiftUI works with points and no screen has `10000` point width or height (I don't know any at least, otherwise the value can be added a zero and its fine).